# Table Inside DIv or Just a div inception

Tags: html, html-table, line

I want a box that has the tittle with a background image/color, then a divisory line and beneath a few thumbnails.

Should I make a div, then put a table inside it, the table would have 2 lines, one small for the tittle and the other would be bigger to show the images.

OR

A small div bar for the tittle and another one right beneath for the images?

Comment: Can you provide an example? Maybe an image or a URL that demonstrates what you are trying to do. Also some code or a jsFiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Actually, I made another question, which explains better what I have in mind. Maybe you should check it out instead! I'll delete this one in a minute I guess :P